# My external JAR file libraries are not showing up in 'External Libraries' after import

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, jar, libraries

I have a JAR file that I am trying to import as a library to use. I have it in my libs folder. I have the following command in Gradle

```
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

However, I do not see this library in my External Libraries tree when examining my project. I see all of the remote com.blahblahblah libraries but none from the JAR files. Any idea why?

Even when I put the jar file in libs, and use this Gradle command:

```
 compile files('libs/semantics3_jarjar.jar')
```

It doesn't seem to see any of the classes within this Jar file.

Answer (score 1):

The External Libraries section in AndroidStudio displays the aar dependencies, not the jar files used in the project.

In any case, the module is able to use it.